# If differential 1-forms agree on chains with integer coefficients, are they equal?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a real, smooth manifold.  Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be differential 1-forms on $M$, and let $C_1(\mathbb Z,M)$ denote the set of 1-chains with integer coefficients.

If
\begin{align}
  \int_c\omega_1 = \int_c\omega_2
\end{align}
for all $c\in C_1(\mathbb Z,M)$, then does $\omega_1=\omega_2$?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I am not so familiar with cohomology; if I restrict the topology of the manifold in some way, can I ensure that they are equal?

Comment: Sorry,  I just saw that you are talking about chains rather than cycles (closed chains). In this case it is true

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Haha ok thanks.  I was just so confused; I went back to "Calculus on Manifolds" to make sure I wasn't going crazy.  So the original result I wrote is true, regardless of topology?  If so, is there a simple proof?

Comment: Choose a base point and integrate the difference along paths.  This gives you a function on the universal cover which by assumption is the zero function. Its differential descends down to a differential back on the original manifold,  which by construction is the difference of the two differentials we started with, yet is zero.  Thus the two differentials are equal

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Ah interesting ok.  I need to learn what the universal cover is, but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Let $\omega$ be a 1-form on $M$. You need to show that $\omega$ vanishes if its integral along all curves in $M$ vanishes.  Fix a point $x\in M$ and $v\in T_x M$ and integrate $\omega$ along  a curve starting in $x$ in the  direction of $v$. By making the curve shorter and shorter, these integrals give better and better approximations to $\omega(v)$, hence $\omega(v)$ must vanish.

Comment: Thanks; that's a nice argument.